# How to log authentication failures on IIS

Tags: security, iis, iis-8

My client is trying to access the Web Service from the web but it is getting http error Forbidden.
I don't know if the problem is on my service or if it is on the client proxy service.
How can i set IIS to log failure attempts too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found out. The login failures are logged into eventlog system. 
They can be retrived by searching for event id 4625 on event viewer.